# Understanding linked list sorting

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am having trouble understanding how this bit of code sorts a linked list.

```
node* sort(node *head) {
    struct node* point;
    struct node* small;
    struct node* stay;
    int temp;
    stay = head;

    while (stay != NULL) {
        point = stay->next;
        small = stay;
        while (point != NULL) {
            if (point->data < small->data) {
                small = point;
            }
            point = point->next;
        }
        temp = stay->data;
        stay->data = small->data;
        small->data = temp;
        stay = stay->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

I have tried to follow it along on paper and my thought process leads me to believe that if we were to run this function, a list would be sorted like this:

```
5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3  
2 -> 5 -> 1 -> 3  
2 -> 1 -> 5 -> 3  
2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 5
```

My understanding is that the first while loop traverses the list each time until it reaches the last node, while the second while loop compares the two nodes `point` and `small`. If the data needs to be switched, the next block of code actually does the switching, and then `stay` moves on to the next node in the list, with `point` being the node after that. How does the code know to go back to the very first node and keep comparing, so that 2 gets switched with 1? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this looks like a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) to me.

Comment: @tonysdg Your not, it *is*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code implements *selection* sort: Starting from `stay` (`small == stay`), it searches for the least value following and as soon as found (i. e. end of list reached) swaps.

Be aware that in case of `stay` being smallest, it is swapped with itself (you could prevent this with an appropriate test before: `if(small != stay) { /* swap */ }`.

So actually, your sorting steps are as follows:

```
5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3
1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3
1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 (second node swapped with itself)
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 (fourth node swapped with itself)
```

Actually, there is one step more, as the last node always is swapped with itself (`while(stay != NULL)` stops only *after* last node).

First node is treated correctly right from the start (in the first run of the outer loop) as `stay` is initially set to `head`.

Comment: Ah, so the does the second while loop run multiple times until it reaches the end of the list , and then after that the `swap` runs? (And then after that, the first while loop runs again) ?

Comment: Yes. That's the nature of nested loops... More generally: control blocks are executed until they are completed, no matter in which context they are (e. g. within another loop). Seen from the context, you can think of a control block as if being executed in a subroutine (separate function).